# What program can I use to generate diagrams of SQL view/table structure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, diagram

I've been tasked with redesigning part of a ms-sql database structure which currently involves a lot of views, some of which contain joins to other views.

Anyway, I wonder if anyone here could recommend a utility to automatically generate diagrams to help me visualise the whole structure.

What's the best program you've used for such problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am a big fan of Embarcadero's [ER/Studio](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/er-studio).  It is very powerful and produces excellent on-screen as well as printed results.  They have a free trial as well, so you should be able to get in and give it a shot without too much strife.

Good luck!

Comment: Link is broken. Can now be found here: http://www.embarcadero.com/products/er-studio

Answer (score 2):

Toad Data Modeller from Quest does a nice job on this and is reasonably priced.  Embarcadero E/R studio is good too, as Bruce mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

OP asked about diagramming views and view dependencies, SQL Management Studio and Enterprise Manager doesn't allow you to diagram views. I can't vouch for the other tools.

The LINQ to SQL designer for Visual Studio does allow you to drop views on the design surface but there isn't a easy way to model the dependencies between the views. I'm not sure which tool has this type of diagramming functionality. You could take a look at Red Gate's SQLDoc tool but it just provides text based output.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about MS SQL Server tables, I like the diagram support in SQL Server Management Studio.  You just drag the tables from the explorer onto the canvas, and they are laid out for you along with lines for relationships.  You'll have to do some adjusting by hand for the best looking diagrams, but it is a decent way to get diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

I upmodded Mark's post about Toad Data Modeler and wanted to point out that they have a beta version that is fully functional and free. The only downsides are the occasional bug and built in expiration (typically around the time a new beta is available), but for this poor bloke it does wonders until I can get my boss to chip in for a license.